# how I can fix the apt.conf? I don't need of the proxy

Tags: apt

So, I'm going to solve my issue, I found the apt.conf to be responsible of a apt-get malfunction. I need a no proxy setting in it.
How to fix it?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Add an answer, or accept an existing one if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then run this to edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If it has a line that looks like:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.1.1:3142";
```

comment it out (put `//` in front of it):

```
// Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.1.1:3142";
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor.

Comment: I think you are right, I see this just now, but I did a change on the string in this way: 'Acquire::http::Proxy DIRECT;' What you think about it?

Comment: Yes, it works. `DIRECT` tells `apt` to not use a proxy.

Comment: @EricCarvalho `#` will not comment a line in `apt.conf`. You can add any external config file using `#include .. `, rather put `//` at the beginning to comment out a line.

Comment: @souravc I didn't test `#include`, but I'm sure `#` can be used to comment out lines. Look at [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16150699/).

Comment: @EricCarvalho In that case I think it lost its functionality in presence of the `#` but it is not the proper way to comment out. Please see the [`man apt.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html) SYNTAX part.

Comment: Please edit the answer with `//` instead of `#`

Comment: It seems that as of present -- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html#syntax -- either of `//`, `/* ... */`, or `#` would work to denote comments